# Set vertical dock priority over horizontal with DockPanel Suite

Tags: c#, winforms, docking, dockpanel-suite

I'm using [DockPanel Suite](http://dockpanelsuite.com/) but I've run into an issue due to the relatively sparse documentation.

I have two docked panels: one which docks left and right, called "Side", and one which docks on the bottom, called "Bottom". I would like Side to fill the height of the form, with Bottom filling up the rest.

So what I'm aiming for is this:
[image: Side dock fill]

But what I have instead is this:
[image: Bottom dock fill]

When I run the program, I get the second variant, and if I drag Bottom out to float it, then drag it back, it will dock the way I want it to, but I can't achieve this programmatically.

Here's my code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SideForm side = new SideForm();
    side.Show(dockPanel, DockState.DockRight);

    BottomForm bottom = new BottomForm();
    bottom.Show(dockPanel, DockState.DockBottom);
}
```

I've tried changing the order, but that has no effect. I've tried poking around the various properties and methods, but there's not much documentation, so IntelliSense is not much help here.

### Update

I've tried bringing the side panel to front and/or sending the bottom panel to back as two people have suggested, but that had no effect. Here's the full code for that:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SideForm side = new SideForm();
    side.Show(dockPanel, DockState.DockRight);

    BottomForm bottom = new BottomForm();
    bottom.Show(dockPanel, DockState.DockBottom);

    // I've tried enabling these one at a time, and even both at once, no effect
    side.BringToFront();
    bottom.SendToBack();
}
```

User Lex Li made another suggestion about first creating a document then docking to the bottom of that. That seemed to work, except now there is no in the bottom window, as follows:

[image: No titlebar]

Here is the code I used to create this:

```
doc = new Document();
doc.Show(dockPanel, DockState.Document);

side = new SideForm();
side.Show(dockPanel, DockState.DockRight);

bottom = new BottomForm();
bottom.Show(doc.Pane, DockAlignment.Bottom, 0.3);
```

I can avoid this by setting the main dockpanel's `DocumentStyle` property to `DockingMdi` or `DockingWindow`, which gives me this:

[image: Tabs]

But then those tabs are there, which I don't want; I prefer to use `DockingSdi` style.

So, I'm trying to *programatically* achieve docking to the very bottom, like this:
Showing the location of the dock...
[image: Starting to dock]

And finally, the docked window
[image: Docked]

Comment: I have not worked with side DockPanel Suite but have you tried something alike: side.BringToFrom(); bottom.SendToBack();

Comment: Yes, I tried both. No effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the record: to change docking priority, you need to customize the Z-order of DockWindow's. Place this:

```
dockPanel.UpdateDockWindowZOrder(DockStyle.Right, true);
```

between InitializeComponent() and the creation/docking of the child forms.

Comment: Wow, this works exactly the way I wanted it to! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try with Control.BringToFrom() and\or control.SendToBack()?

```
SideForm side = new SideForm();
side.Show(dockPanel, DockState.DockRight);

BottomForm bottom = new BottomForm();
bottom.Show(dockPanel, DockState.DockBottom);

side.BringToFrom();
```

*or*

```
bottom.SendToBack();
```

Comment: Yes I've tried, but neither bringing to front or sending to back had any effect.

Comment: I tried with that code and worked, can you share the full code?